# Initialize map with pin, but not centered

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have application with google map v2, containing one marker. When map is loaded i want to position marker on top of the map, and not centered (example x=mapWidth/2, y=mapHeight/4). Example:

[image]

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Setting a marker does (AFAIK) not automatically center the map at the markers position.

Comment: The question is how to position the marker, so it to be on the top of map, as shown on image.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the width and height of the map you can use a projection to find the corresponding LatLng coordinate:

```
public void setMarkerAtTop(GoogleMap map, int width, int height) {
    projection = map.getProjection();
    Point p = new Point(width / 2, height / 4);
    LatLng latLng = projection.fromScreenLocation(p);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
}
```

How to get width and height depends on whether you use a MapView or a MapFragment.
For a View its just getWidth and getHeight. For MapFragment use getView at first.